# How to remove following npm install error?

Tags: node.js, angular, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am trying to run the following project:
https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-in-angular
This repo is simply an example of using React in AngularJS. There are three tags. Check them out in order to see the process of moving an Angular app to React. Kinda fun and stuff :-)

But after npm install i am getting following error:

```
npm WARN rm not removing /home/user/react-in-angular/node_modules/.bin/esparse as it wasn't installed by /home/user/react-in-angular/node_modules/esprima-fb
npm WARN rm not removing /home/user/react-in-angular/node_modules/.bin/esvalidate as it wasn't installed by /home/user/react-in-angular/node_modules/esprima-fb

> kexec@1.1.0 install /home/user/react-in-angular/node_modules/kexec
> pangyp configure build

sh: 1: pangyp: not found
npm WARN react-in-angular@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@0.3.8 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@0.3.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: kexec@1.1.0 (node_modules/kexec):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: kexec@1.1.0 install: `pangyp configure build`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn ENOENT

added 126 packages from 149 contributors, removed 72 packages, updated 570 packages and audited 7724 packages in 10.882s

17 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 7 vulnerabilities (2 low, 5 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

After runnung npm audit:

```
                       === npm audit security report ===                        


                                 Manual Review                                  
             Some vulnerabilities require your attention to resolve             

          Visit https://go.npm.me/audit-guide for additional guidance           


  Low             Arbitrary File Write                                          

  Package         cli                                                           

  Patched in      >=1.0.0                                                       

  Dependency of   6to5 [dev]                                                    

  Path            6to5 > jshint > cli                                           

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/95                               


  High            Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         minimatch                                                     

  Patched in      >=3.0.2                                                       

  Dependency of   6to5 [dev]                                                    

  Path            6to5 > chokidar > readdirp > minimatch                        

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/118                              


  High            Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         minimatch                                                     

  Patched in      >=3.0.2                                                       

  Dependency of   6to5 [dev]                                                    

  Path            6to5 > jshint > cli > glob > minimatch                        

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/118                              


  High            Regular Expression Denial of Service                          

  Package         minimatch                                                     

  Patched in      >=3.0.2                                                       

  Dependency of   6to5 [dev]                                                    

  Path            6to5 > jshint > minimatch                                     

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/118                              


  Low             Prototype Pollution                                           

  Package         lodash                                                        

  Patched in      >=4.17.5                                                      

  Dependency of   6to5 [dev]                                                    

  Path            6to5 > lodash                                                 

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/577                              


  High            Prototype Pollution                                           

  Package         lodash                                                        

  Patched in      >=4.17.11                                                     

  Dependency of   6to5 [dev]                                                    

  Path            6to5 > lodash                                                 

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/782                              


  High            Prototype Pollution                                           

  Package         lodash                                                        

  Patched in      >=4.17.12                                                     

  Dependency of   6to5 [dev]                                                    

  Path            6to5 > lodash                                                 

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1065                             

found 7 vulnerabilities (2 low, 5 high) in 7724 scanned packages
  7 vulnerabilities require manual review. See the full report for details.
```

After running, webpack-dev-server --content-base app:

```
validateSchema is not a function
```

How can solve it ?

Comment: Did you try deleting node_modules and running npm install again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following things

**1) Uninstall following package:**

npm uninstall webpack webpack-dev-server --save -dev

**2) Install following Packages:**

npm install --save -dev webpack@3.10.0

npm install --save -dev webpack-cli@2.0.10

npm install --save -dev webpack-dev-server@2.9.7

Comment: It started running after doing above. But got new error: ERROR in ./app/index.js
Module build failed: LoaderRunnerError: Module '/home/user/react-in-angular/node_modules/6to5/lib/6to5/index.js' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)

Comment: Delete package-lock.json and yarn.lock.
Check if node_modules/react exists.
If it doesn't, check if react is in your package.json. If you don't have it in package.json, add it.

Run npm install (or yarn if you use it).
Check if node_modules/react exists.

Answer (score 1):

The npm log you are receiving is not an error, and probably is not related with the javascript error you are receiving when executing the code.

The NPM log is only referring to optional dependencies that are being skipped because of the current operating system, and security audits, which are recommended to be fixed, but should not affect to the execution.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the information you've given I'd suggest try running it with the webpack-dev-server that is installed as part of the application as opposed to the webpack-dev-server you've got globally. Adding `"start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base app"` to the package.json and using npm start in the root folder worked for me.

Basing this on [webpack.validateSchema is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40597626/webpack-validateschema-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use npm command prompt while using angular and other frameworks.

Output in  CMD:

```
--> `C:\Users\your_username> ng serve`
==>`'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.`
```

While, the output in Node.js Command Prompt:

```
--> `C:\Users\your_username> ng serve `
==>
```

```
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size
vendor.js             | vendor        |   2.10 MB |
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 318.07 kB |
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 210.10 kB |
main.js               | main          |  50.19 kB |
runtime.js            | runtime       |   6.53 kB |

                  | Initial Total |   2.67 MB

Build at: 2022-09-11T17:09:51.287Z - Hash: 5f09c87536feee1e - Time: 28707ms

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


√ Compiled successfully.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to re install the nodejs new version on the computer

[Node js file download direction](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

(not use the power shell to install use the visual code to run the npm install)